# How to query a two-way friendship?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL DB I am planning on storing friendships two-way after reading an article on this.

A->B
B->A

If a friendship is stored only one way, then that would mean that a friendship hasn't been confirmed yet, or removed or whatsoever.

The only thing I am wondering now is how to query this?

If I'm querying all a user's friends. How do I get only the confirmed friendships? Do I sort out the unconfirmed friendships later by going over the array or is there a query I can use for this?

Also how would this work for the inverse? What's the query for getting only the unconfirmed friendships?

**EDIT**

Using Laravel for this one, the query is made within the model:

```
$friendsCollection = $this->where('user_a', '=', $currentUserId)->orWhere('user_b', '=', $currentUserId)->get();
```

This will give me all the rows where the current user is either user_a or user_b in a friendship.

Now my question is how to weed out the "broken" connections? Where only one of the two rows is existing?

Also it just occured to me is how to paginate this when a user starts having many many friends.

Comment: Plain theory doen't work here. Code speaks at stackoverflow. Please post what have you tried

Comment: When you mentioned `two-way friendships` I got a warm fuzzy feeling.

Comment: Seems like you should have a friend requests table and a friends table.  A one-way friendship doesn't really exist in your setup, so it shouldn't be stored in the same table.

Comment: That's correct @Devon requests and friendships are in separate tables.

Comment: just show us what you have. Then we can be BFF

Comment: @Drew alright give me a moment...

Comment: @Drew, well as it appears while I was busy coming translating my laravel to a raw example Esteban answered the question. Up until the point of the query to get the values out of the DB he has everything set up the way I have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tables can look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE users(
    userId int  PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE friendship(
    userId int NOT NULL,
    friendId int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userId, friendId)
);
```

Insert some values:

```
insert into users VALUES (1, 'a');
insert into users VALUES (2, 'b');
insert into users VALUES (3, 'c');

insert into friendship VALUES (1,2);
insert into friendship VALUES (2,1);
insert into friendship VALUES (1,3);
```

So your query to look for two-way friendships can look like this:

```
SELECT u1.username, u2.username
FROM friendship f1
LEFT JOIN users u1
  ON u1.userId = f1.userId
LEFT JOIN users u2
  ON u2.userId = f1.friendId
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friendship f2 WHERE f2.userId = f1.friendId)
```

Result:

```
username username
------------------
  a         b
  b         a
```

And the query for one-way (unconfirmed) friendships can look like this:

```
SELECT u1.username, u2.username
FROM friendship f1
LEFT JOIN users u1
  ON u1.userId = f1.userId
LEFT JOIN users u2
  ON u2.userId = f1.friendId
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM friendship f2 WHERE f2.userId = f1.friendId)
```

Result:

```
username username
------------------
  a         c
```

Comment: Thank you so much Esteban! Will give it a try right away!

Comment: Took me a bit more time in the end but you've definitely helped me into the right direction @Esteban! Thank you so much! :)